# Relation between the Cohomology of a $G-$submodule

Tags: group-cohomology

Let $G$ be any group and $M$ any $G-$module. Suppose that $N$ is a $G$-submodule of $M$. Is there a relation between the cohomology groups $H^{i}(G,N)$ and $H^{i}(G,M)$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology#Long_exact_sequence_of_cohomology

Comment: A $G$-submodule $N$ of $M$ is a $G$-monomorphism $N \to M$. The cohomology groups are functors, so in all dimensions they induce maps $H^q(G,N)\to H^q(G,M)$. From the long exact sequence in cohomology we also have maps $H^q(G,M)\to H^q(G,M/N) \to H^{q+1}(G,N)$ coming from the short exact sequence $0 \to N \to M \to M/N \to 0$. All of this is found in the Wikipedia article linked by hunter.